# Match XML Attribute by Attribute Name? XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt, attributes

How can I find attribute values based on a regular expression of the attribute name in xslt?  In this snippet, I am trying to match attributes like "url.title", or "page.title", etc... anything with ".title".

```
<attribute name="withRegexp">
  <value-of select='matches(@*[name()], "\.title")'/>
</attribute>
```

That doesn't work, any ideas what to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 you can match attribute nodes whose name ends in `.title` with:

```
@*[matches(name(), '\.title$')]
```

In XPath 1.0 there are no regular expression matching functions. To get attribute nodes whose name contains the substring `.title` you can use:

```
@*[contains(name(), '.title')]
```